# Is it possible to rsnapshot localsource to remotetarget?

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

Since rsnapshot is based on rsync I wanted to try to use rsnapshot on my client server to backup to a remote server. The Problem is I am unable to find proper informations to set this up. I now how to use rsync to save files/dirs from my client server to my remote server but struggle with the rsnapshot conf.

My initial thought was I just switch source and target inside the rsnapshot.conf file:

LocalSource -> LocalDestionation:

```
backup    /home/    localhost
```

to LocalSource -> RemoteDestination:

```
backup    /home/    user@remote.com:/volume1/Backups
```

It seems this is not working since `rsnapshot -t daily` results in:

```
echo 4069 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
mkdir -m 0755 -p \
    /var/cache/rsnapshot/daily.0/user@remote.com:/volume1/Backups/
/usr/bin/rsync -a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded \
    /home/ \
    /var/cache/rsnapshot/daily.0/user@remote.com:/volume1/Backups/remote.com/
touch /var/cache/rsnapshot/daily.0/
```

and running rsnapshot not in testmode also just saves them to rsnapshots root directory.

**Is it possible to achieve this?**

I am aware of that the switched situation should work:

RemoteSource -> LocalDestination:

```
backup    user@client.com:/home/    localhost
```

Comment: I was trying to figure it out myself and supposedly no.

Comment: At the end we implement a service on the backup server. I think I want to let this question open, because their is no solution at the moment.

Comment: Like I said, the answer to this question is most likely: "This is not possible with `rsnapshot`." Check out [the docs](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/rsnapshot/rsnapshot.1.en). If you want to back up *from* `localhost`, there's a number of alternative tools: [`borgbackup`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/0f856d233b1bb8f1ee3e17ce80731c5e), [`restic`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/315fd5eb922efe40a7e35d59452a1876), [`duplicity`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/51bbf766926fe6247cd989c4db27e58d), [`rdiff-backup`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/b9de829a91611ce078541757a499a97c).

Comment: Which doesn't mean you should close (or delete) the question.